# Azure blob storage DownloadTextAsync with BlobRequestOptions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Using azure blob storage and the Azure SDK, I currently am downloading a string like so:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobUid);
var text = await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
```

I want to pass in a blobRequestOptions to set a custom retry policy so it would look like this:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobUid);
var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions()
{
     RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 3)
};

var text await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync(encoding, accessCondition, blobRequestOptions, operationContext);
```

My problem is I am not sure what to pass in for encoding, accessCondition or operationContext.  I have looked at the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434829.aspx) and did a bunch of searching but I cannot figure out what to pass in.

Encoding: My data is just json in Us-En so I think I would be fine with ACSII or UTF-8 but I cannot find if azure has a default I should be using.

AccessCondition and OperationContext: No idea what I should be passing in.

Or maybe there is a better way to do what I am trying to do without using the overloaded DownloadTextAsync.

Comment: you can try the overloads without these parameters https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtextasync.aspx  or you can search msdn for each of those parameters for example Accesscondition has so many enum options https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.accesscondition.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have a problem like this and I'm lucky enough that the SDK is open-source, I usually check out the source code.
Source code for the Azure Storage SDK is here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net

So this is the method that you are calling:

```
public virtual Task<string> DownloadTextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   return AsyncExtensions.TaskFromApm(this.BeginDownloadText, this.EndDownloadText, cancellationToken);
}
```

This just basically converts the `BeginDownloadText` method from the old APL model to the new TPL-based call. If you check out BeginDownloadText:

```
public virtual ICancellableAsyncResult BeginDownloadText(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    return this.BeginDownloadText(null /* encoding */, null /* accessCondition */, null /* options */, null /* operationContext */, callback, state);
}
```

You can see that they are explicitly specifying `null` values for the encoding, the accessCondition and the operationContext. You can drill even further down if you want, but I'd say you're OK using `null` for the parameters you don't need.

Comment: Its funny, I keep forgetting that the MS stuff is open source these days.  Thanks.

Comment: It's a brave new world :) Happy to help.